# What is $\int x^re^xdx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there any simple way to get integral of $e^{x}x^{r}, r \in \mathbb{R}$?

Basically I want to solve this:

$$\displaystyle \int \frac{e^t(4t^2+1)}{2t \sqrt{t}}dt$$

so I will appreciate any help in both of the above problems.

Comment: Maple expresses $\int x^r e^x dx$ in terms of the incomplete Gamma function, but only because that is essentially the definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** Break up the integral into two integrals
$$
\int \frac{e^t(4t^2 + 1)}{2t \sqrt{t}} dt = \int 2e^t \sqrt{t} dt + \int \frac{e^t}{2t^{3/2}}dt
$$

Then use integration by parts on one of them until you have a constant multiple of the other, and see what happens.

Note: In general, we can't find $\int e^x x^r dx$. The definite integral $\int_0^\infty x^r e^x dx$ is (almost) the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: I integrated by parts twice first integral and then the sum of both integrals become zero.

Comment: @user78545: Exactly!